# AngularJS: Auto reload

Tags: angularjs

What is the most conventional way to make an AngularJS single page app automatically reload in the browser every time I change its code?

In other words, if I have a code editor open editing the HTML for the AnguarJS single page app, and a browser at that app, side-by-side on the same screen, hitting Save in my editor should instantly trigger the browser to refresh.

Alternatively, same scenario as above except instead of hitting Save on my editor, I did a Commit in my VCS.

Comment: why not use http://yeoman.io/? for the live reload thats built-in

Answer (score 1):

Use [Grunjs watch task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) for this.

Answer (score 0):

That is the work of your task runner like gulp or grunt to watch the changes over specified files and perform action. None of this is related to angularjs

Comment: I have same question how we will reload anguler js application if any thing changed in application (file- add/remove ,js changed, css modify). Which is   best implement-ion for same. We have nginx proxy server as web application server